# How would I go about developing a time line plot for survival analysis?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm presently using the "veteran" dataset and would like to build a time line but am not sure as to how I would get started. Basically, the following is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Survival analysis time line]

The dataset has two time-based values: "time" and "diagtime."

"Time" - From treatment to event

"diagtime" - From diagnosis to study entry

I would like to build a time line such that **dashes** represent time between diagnosis to study entry, or "diagtime", **solid lines** represent the time after study entry, and **dots** represent death. Essentially, the solid lines and the dots would be connected if there were deaths because you're going from the time after study entry to potentially death. If there is no death, you would just have a solid line.

The status refers to censoring status:

1 = censored;
0 = uncensored.

I have attached the first five data to show you what it looks like:

[First five data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4PxW.png)

The entire dataset can be found by doing the following:

```
library("survival")

veteran
```

I have downloaded ggplot2, but I am not sure how to get started. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with a combination of `geom_segment` and `geom_point`.

I use a logarithmic scale in the x axis because the ranges of `time` and `diagtime` are very different.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(dplyr)

data(cancer, package="survival")

range(veteran$time)
#[1]   1 999
range(veteran$diagtime)
#[1]  1 87

veteran %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = id)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = id, yend = diagtime), y = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = id, y = diagtime, yend = time)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = time, size = status), shape = 16, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0, 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  ylab(expression(log[10] ~ "(time)")) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I greatly appreciate it, man. The only change I pretty much made was I added the "diagtime" and the "time" so that the time would represent the total number of days from diagnosis to event. That way, the log10 (time) can be represented as log10 (days).